# image_graph primer

Tags: php, graph, matrix, pear

Anyone know of a good primer for Pear's image_graph libraries? I have Jesper Veggerby's sample code but I need something more detailed that gives syntax and usage rules. I am having problems generating a matrix of graphs  - I either get the same data replicated on all graphs in the matrix or I only the leftmost column of graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use Image_Graph but one of the other libraries, for example the ez Component Graph lib. It has fewer bugs and looks nicer.